# Does Blazor or MudBlazor allow for CSS packing

Tags: css, webpack, blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

With traditional JavaScript frameworks, using packing frameworks such as WebPack help to optimise payload sizes.

There is a lot less JavaScript (unless we use JS Interop) with Blazor.

Does MudBlazor or Blazor allow for any CSS minification? I noticed that the CSS comes out in full form in the HTML that is rendered.

[image: Mud Blazor CSS that is not packed]

Answer (score 1):

I use BuildBundlerMinifier nuget package on my blazor app and it works. You need to create a new json file **bundleconfig.json** with this inside:

```
[
   {
     "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bundle.min.css",
     "inputFiles": [
     "wwwroot/css/app.css",
     "wwwroot/css/site.css"
     ]
   },
   {
     "outputFileName": "wwwroot/scripts/bundle.min.js",
     "inputFiles": [
     "wwwroot/scripts/core.js",
     "wwwroot/scripts/index.js"
     ],
     "minify": {
     "enabled": true,
     "renameLocals": true
     },
     "sourceMap": false
   }
]
```

After you build your app you will get the new files and only need to reference those on your app

Comment: This seems to be for Blazor, not MudBlazor?

Comment: @User101 as you ask for blazor or mudBlazor, think it would help a blazor solution, let me modify my mudblazor project and see the behaviour!

Comment: @User101 with mud blazor, changing the js reference, the behaviour of the component library doesn't work as expected since the bundle is modifying the properties that mudblazor reference, if you make a js file similar to the mudblazor one, it could work as expected!

Comment: thanks, but does this just bundle your custom js? Or the js that comes with mudblazor/blazor? Also will this solution minify css names too?